# TemplateSyntaxError: inlines is not a valid tag library

Tags: django, django-templates, django-apps

Building my Django app, I have been using some code from [django-basic-app](https://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps), in particular the `inlines` application.

In my `blog` app, I load `inlines` in a template (here in `blog/templates/admin/blog/change_form.html`)

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block extrahead %}
  {% load adminmedia inlines %}
  {{ block.super }}
```

When I do that, I have an error

> TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/blog/post/1/
>
> 'inlines' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading
>   inlines.templatetags.inlines: No module named models

The structure of the project is

```
blog/
    templates/admin/blog/
                        change_form.html
    ...
inlines/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
           __init__.py
           inlines.py
    ...
```

and with the import in `inlines/templatetags/inlines.py`

```
from django import template
from inlines.models import InlineType
from inlines.parser import inlines
import re
```

`inlines` is present in `INSTALLED_APPS` and I am using Django 1.4 with python 2.7

I am trying to have a standalone application (not linked to the project then) but I don't get why it is not detected by the blog app. The inlines models are detected by django, I am able to manage it using the admin interface, just the templatetags is failing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to rename `inlines.py` module to `inlines_tags.py` for example, so a module and a package will not be same named. And dont forget to remove all old `*.pyc` files from templatetags folder

Comment: for some odd reason my app should be the first in INSTALLED_APPS in order to work properly..